# Sitecore "webedit:sortcontent" command

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I am wondering if it it possible to call the command "webedit:sortcontent" with an ID or datasource. Do you have to use an editframe for this or can you pass a parameter with ID?

I tried calling it directly from javascript, like this: `Sitecore.PageModes.ChromeManager.postRequest('webedit:sortcontent(' + myid + ')');`, with no luck.

Comment: `Sitecore.PageModes.ChromeManager.postRequest('webedit:sortcontent(id="id")');` gives me a message. "Item "{0}" not found". And `(itemid="id");` gives me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sitecore.PageModes.ChromeManager.postRequest('webedit:sortcontent(itemid=' + id + ')');
```

This seems to work.